# XSD Syntax with Restrictions and Default values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Is this the right format for XSD integer with restrictions?  My goal is to restrict the input from 1 to 10 and default to 5. I found a lot of examples with restrictions and default. But nothing with both of them together.

```
<xs:element name="age" default="5">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:sequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your use of default and restricted values is correct.

Keep in mind that default values are only for simple types.  Also, default values for ***attributes*** apply when the attribute is ***absent***, but default values for ***elements*** apply when the element is ***empty***.